# React - vanilla select value not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

I have a simple vanilla select in my component:

Content.js:

```
state = {
    langValue: 'fr'
};

handleChange = event => {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ value: newValue }, () =>
        this.props.onChangeLanguage(newValue)
    );
};

render() {
  return (
      <select value={this.state.langValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="fr">Français</option>
          <option value="en">English</option>
      </select>
  );
}
```

The onChangeLanguage method is called and translations are updated but the value of the select is not changing. If I remove the callback in the set state, the select value is updating but the language is not updated (which is normal)

App.js:

```
...

let i18nConfig = {
    locale: navigator.language.split(/[-_]/)[0],
    messages: getMessagesFromLang(navigator.language.split(/[-_]/)[0])
};

const [lang, setLang] = React.useState(i18nConfig.locale); // keeps state of lang in App
function onChangeLanguage(lang) {
    setLang(lang); // changes the lang when selec value changes
}

...
```

Comment: `value={this.state.langValue}` should be `value={this.state.value}`. Or, you need to change `this.setState({ value: newValue })` to `this.setState({ langValue: newValue })`. Pick one.

Comment: Yep, thx. Should have seen that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the state property of `value`:

```js
this.setState({ value: newValue }
```

but then using it as `langValue`

```js
<select value={this.state.langValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
```

Change one to match the other and it will work.

---

Regarding your comment, the snippet below proves that the code as is does work as expected. If you are having issues with the select value not updating, my guess is it must be a side-effect of the prop function.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
      langValue: 'fr'
  };

  handleChange = event => {
      const newValue = event.target.value;
      this.setState({ langValue: newValue }, () =>
          console.log('call your prop function')
      );
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <select value={this.state.langValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="fr">Français</option>
            <option value="en">English</option>
        </select>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Indeed, should have seen that ><

But another issue pops up. I have to select the value twice to see the change.
The first click, the translations change.
The second click, the value of the select changes.

Comment: If I remove my call to onChangeLanguage and put a log like you. It's working.
It seems it the onChangeLanguage that causes the issue like you said.

Comment: I edited my question with some details from the props method

Comment: I tried to remove the code inside the props method and it's still not working. So it's the fact of calling a props method that causes the issue

Comment: In complement to your answer, I changed the App function component to a class component, and change the functions inside it to methods and it's working. Thx